# Form validation for Power Automate Start and wait for an approval

Tags: power-automate

I'm writing a Power Automate flow for an internal process. The item being approved is an uploaded file. If the file is approved, all is well, and it should move on normally. If the file is not approved, approver comments will need to be required. How can I accomplish this in Power Automate?

Currently, I'm trying to use "Start and wait for an approval". I've seen a few suggestions that would require a loop. That just seems to be more steps than it needs to be.

Comment: Are you using the built-in approvals connector? It's designed to handle approvals (as you might guess), including rejections.

Comment: If the standard operation doesn’t do what you want, you could use an adaptive card. You’ll have to forgo all of the standard stuff given  to you though by the approval framework. Or, you could send the adaptive card after the fact asking for a reason if one wasn’t provided.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to use the built in approval connector. If I can't, I've never used custom cards in Power Automate. Where would be some good resources to learn about them?